# Why in oauth callback url is not redirecting me to onResume() in android?

Tags: android, url, oauth, callback, onresume

i need your help to find out why the callback url is not working with me as i can't fo back to onResume in the activity

here is the code i use

```
    public class OAuthTrialsActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "66aba0d1168566c364d86e6087bea04e04e9ff754";
        private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "aec138c913cb21763b4983de77683a04";
        private static final int CALL_BACK = 1;

        private static String ACCESS_KEY = null;
        private static String ACCESS_SECRET = null;


        private static final String REQUEST_URL = "http://yakhabar.tawasoldev.com/index.php/api/requestToken";
        private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "http://yakhabar.tawasoldev.com//index.php/api/accessToken";
        private static final String AUTH_URL = "http://yakhabar.tawasoldev.com/index.php/api/AuthorizeApp";
        private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "http://localhost/app.php?third=true";

        private static CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
                    CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
        private static CommonsHttpOAuthProvider provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(
        REQUEST_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, AUTH_URL); 


        Button btnLogin;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            provider.setOAuth10a(true);
            btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                        String authURL = provider.retrieveRequestToken(
                                            consumer, CALLBACK_URL);

                    Log.d("OAuthTwitter authURL", authURL);
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                            .parse(authURL)));


                } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            });
        }
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
        Log.d("ana shoftha","ahmed"+uri);
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
            Log.d("ana shoftha","ahmed");
            Log.d("OAuthTwitter uri", uri.toString());
            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
            Log.d("OAuthTwitter verifier", verifier);
            try {

                provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, verifier);
                ACCESS_KEY = consumer.getToken();
                ACCESS_SECRET = consumer.getTokenSecret();

                Log.d("OAuthTwitter key ", ACCESS_KEY);
                Log.d("OAuthTwitter secret", ACCESS_SECRET);

            } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".OAuthTrialsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="localhost" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

the service directs me to the callback url with the verifier but i can extract it because i don't go back to the activity

can anyone help and give me a solution please

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue today. On Twitter I did not have a Callback URL specified on the settings page. After I added that my onReceive started working.  The url can be anything, not specific to your application.  Hope this helps!

Comment: have you checked the same in android ICS